# How to show metadata input on a document library's "New Document" form

Tags: document-library, document, form, metadata

I'm trying to show metadata fields on the 'New Document' form of a library.

I have setup my custom content type with the fields I need, and added it to the library.

When I upload a document, I have the option to set the custom fields directly on the form, is this an option as well when creating a new document?

Answer (score 0):

There is no New Form for document libraries, only display and edit forms. The new form is the Word document template or Excel, ect. Any metadata you have in your document library would show in in the document information panel of the office application, or if in 2016, show up backstage by clicking the back arrow in the upper left of the application. This will allow you to set metadata for the file.

This only works when authoring new documents in the client application, it will not be available in Office Web Apps (document creation in the browser).